# Dial via SIP -> IAX2

Tags: asterisk

In one of my asterisk boxes (box-A) I have a SIP trunk to another box (box-B) which has an IAX2 trunk to a third box (box-C). From box-A I would like to trigger an IAX2 call to box-C, via the SIP trunk to box-B.

If I was in box-B I would just simply do:

```
Dial(IAX2/box-C/9999)
```

But I am in box-A. How can I trigger this IAX2 call from box-A -> box-B -> box-C?

Comment: Why not create another IAX2 trunk or create a bridge?

Comment: I do not think a bridge is appropriate (what to bridge, we are talking here SIP and IAX2, from two different boxes to a third box). Creating another iax2 trunk is also not feasible: box-C only allows iax2 calls from box-B.

Answer (score 0):

You have write dialplan on box-B so it call to box-C when call come from box-A.

After that call from box-A with a prefix in the dialplan.

For more info read some books like ["Asterisk: The Future of Telephony"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596510480.do)